# Comparação de array em java

Tags: java, java-ee

Estava fazendo um projeto e precisei da seguinte lógica... https://www.devmedia.com.br/multiplos-resultsets-em-java/21152
e me deparei com a seguinte situação... e se fosse com 2 consultas distintas como ficaria? no meu caso eu tenho q comparar o resultado do primeiro select e buscar no segundo os itens q correspondem ao primeiro... pra ser mais especifico eu tenho um select com pacientes que tem atendimentos e eu preciso buscar os atendimentos de cada paciente

Conexao

```
package geradorhtml3;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class Conexao {

    public Connection conFirebird() {

        Connection con = null;
        String driver = "org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDriver";
        String user = "SYSDBA";
        String senha = "masterkey";
        String url = "jdbc:firebirdsql://localhost:3050/D:/firebird/meubanco.FDB";

        try {
            Class.forName(driver);
            con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, senha);
            System.out.println("Conexão realizada com sucesso.");

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) {
            System.err.println(ex.getMessage());

        }
        return con;
    }

}
```

Paciente 
    package geradorhtml3;

```
import java.sql.Date;

public class Paciente {

       private static String nome;  
       private static String cpf;  
       private static String tel;  
       private static Date dataNasc; 

    public static String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public static void setNome(String aNome) {
        nome = aNome;
    }

    public static String getCpf() {
        return cpf;
    }

    public static void setCpf(String aCpf) {
        cpf = aCpf;
    }

    public static String getTel() {
        return tel;
    }

    public static void setTel(String aTel) {
        tel = aTel;
    }

    public static Date getDataNasc() {
        return dataNasc;
    }

    public static void setDataNasc(Date aDataNasc) {
        dataNasc = aDataNasc;
    }


}
```

Ciclos

```
package geradorhtml3;

import java.sql.Date;

public class Ciclo {

    private static String id;
    private static String nome;
    private static String cod_paciente;
    private static Date data;

    public static String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public static void setId(String aId) {
        id = aId;
    }

    public static String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public static void setNome(String aNome) {
        nome = aNome;
    }

    public static String getCod_paciente() {
        return cod_paciente;
    }

    public static void setCod_paciente(String aCod_paciente) {
        cod_paciente = aCod_paciente;
    }

    public static Date getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public static void setData(Date aData) {
        data = aData;
    }



}
```

Aqui se encontra a minha duvida

```
package geradorhtml3;

import java.sql.CallableStatement;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Buscar {

    private static ArrayList c;

    private static ArrayList f;

    public Buscar() {

        try {

            ResultSet[] rs = new ResultSet[2];
            Connection con = new Conexao().conFirebird();
            CallableStatement cs = null;
            //String sql = "SELECT * FROM PACIENTE";            
            //String sql = "SELECT * FROM CICLOS";
            /* 
            Estou tentando juntar esses dois selects os quais tem um relacionamento, 
            porem NÃO pode ser feito no banco, tem q ser feito em codigo a uniao deles
            */

            String sql = "{CALL RETORNA_CLI_FORN()}";

            cs = con.prepareCall(sql);
            rs[0] = cs.executeQuery();

            c = new ArrayList();
            Paciente cl = new Paciente();

            while (rs[0].next()) {

                cl.setNome(rs[0].getString("NOME"));
                cl.setCpf(rs[0].getString("CPF"));
                cl.setTel(rs[0].getString("TEL"));
                cl.setDataNasc(rs[0].getDate("DATA_NASCIMENTO"));
                c.add(cl);

            }

            if (cs.getMoreResults()) {
                rs[1] = cs.getResultSet();
                f = new ArrayList();
                Ciclo fo = new Ciclo();
                while (rs[1].next()) {
                    fo.setNome(rs[1].getString("NOME"));
                    fo.setCod_paciente(rs[1].getString("CNPJ"));
                    f.add(fo);
                }
            }

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Paciente.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

        }

    }

    public Iterator retornaPaciente() {
        Iterator i = c.iterator();
        return i;

    }

    public Iterator retornaCiclo() {
        Iterator i = f.iterator();
        return i;
    }

}
```

MAIN

```
package geradorhtml3;

import java.util.Iterator;

public class GeradorHtml3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Buscar c = new Buscar();
        Iterator _ic = null;
        Iterator _if = null;
        Paciente cl = new Paciente();
        Ciclo fo = new Ciclo();
        _ic = c.retornaPaciente();
        _if = c.retornaCiclo();

        while (_ic.hasNext()) {
            cl = (Paciente) _ic.next();
            System.out.println(
                cl.getNome() + " - " + 
                cl.getCpf() + " -" + 
                cl.getTel() + " - " + 
                cl.getDataNasc());
        }

        while (_if.hasNext()) {
            fo = (Ciclo) _if.next();
            System.out.println(fo.getNome() + " - " + fo.getCod_paciente());

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Não tem como a gente adivinhar o seu código e dar dicas ou dizer o que tem que fazer sem ver o que você tem até aqui. A lógica é uma coisa, a abordagem é outra totalmente diferente. Edite o post e coloca aquilo que você já tem. Não veja como uma crítica, mas está nas regras do SOPT e, caso você não faça, as chances do seu tópico ser apagado são grandes.

Comment: Nos ajude a te ajudar, colega. Coloque seu código, especialmente o que você já tentou fazer para resolver o problema.

Comment: Cara, esse artigo que você linkou é horroroso. Começa com a formatação totalmente zoada e comentários de código totalmente inúteis, mas mesmo ignorando esses e olhando só a lógica implementada, é uma aberração, um festival de más práticas de programação, um dos piores artigos que já li. Esses artigos deveriam ser escritos para informar e ensinar, mas esse daí só faz ensinar errado e confundir. Adoraria escrever uma resposta sobre isso, mas... Que pacientes e atendimentos são esses que você fala? Quais são as tabelas relacionadas?

Answer (score 0):

Recebi algumas Criticas e nenhuma solução para o meu questionamento, porém consegui resolver e vou postar pra ajudar alguem que possa ter a mesma dúvida...

Para varrer 2 Contultas diferentes sendo comparadas e prenchidas via código utilizei a seguinte lógica (bem grosseira, mas funcionou!)

```
public class GeradorHtml2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, FileNotFoundException, SQLException, IOException {

        try {
            Connection conn = new Conectar().conFirebird();
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
            String Html = null;
            ResultSet resultSet1 = stmt.executeQuery(""
                    + "select COD_PACIENTE FROM PACIENTE"
                    + "");

            while (resultSet1.next()) {

                Integer COD_PACIENTE = resultSet1.getInt("COD_PACIENTE");

                System out Println(COD_PACIENTE);

                Statement statement2 = conn.createStatement();
                ResultSet resultSet2 = statement2.executeQuery(""
                        + "select * FROM ATENDIMENTO "
                        + "where COD_PACIENTE IN (" + COD_PACIENTE + ")\n"
                        + "");

                while (resultSet2.next()) {

                    String TRATAMENTO = resultSet2.getString("TRATAMENTO");
                    System out Println(TRATAMENTO);

                }
            }

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```